# Как узнать в какой среде (window или global) выполняется код?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как узнать в какой среде выполняется код (js или nodejs) учитывая что эта проверка должна быть в объекте? И у nodejs ведь 'global'?

Comment: так и проверить если есть _window_ значит браузер, у них же имена конкретные, а не просто _глобальный объект_

Comment: _У ноды аналог `window` это `global`_. `module` - это отдельная вещь. _this.window_ работает в браузере, если не выставлен _"use strict"_

Comment: например, то, что тут `this` указывает на объект _a_, а так как в этом объекте нет свойства _window_ то ожидаемый результат - _undefiend_

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32577/discussion-between-grundy-and-shatal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать следующую функцию

```
function whatIsGlobal(){
    try{
        return GLOBAL && 'node';
    }catch(ex){
        return "browser"
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. и ещё символы чтобы сообщение добавилось.